# Performing a masscan on an input file containing domain names

Tags: linux, bash, security, networking, port

I cannot find any options in order to perform a masscan on an input file containing domain names in the following format:

```
domain-name1.com
domain-name2.org
domain-name3.net
```

Is there a way I could use [masscan](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan) with an input file containing those domain names? If the masscan software cannot perform that, would you see any Linux programs that could it that would be fast like masscan?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Define `masscan`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `nmap`? That will perform a variety of probes against one or more hosts. It's unclear what you want to achieve, though.

Comment: Hi, by masscan I mean this linux program;
https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan

NMap wouldn't be fast enough since i have millions of domain names to perform a scan on them. Masscan is way faster but cannot find a way to make it right

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU's parallel in combination with dig or host to do performative mass DNS resolution. A combination of dig and parallel would be the following:

```sh
parallel -j100 --retries 3 dig @$nameserver +short :::: hosts.txt | grep -E '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' > ip_list.txt
```

- The number after -j switch is the amount of parallel DNS queries you want to execute;
- +short tells dig to output only the DNS resolved addresses;
- grep filters out only IP addresses, so we don't get MX entries, or any other unresolved addresses;
- hosts.txt is the input file, containing hostnames;
- ip_list.txt is the output file, which will be used to feed masscan.

Then you can feed masscan with your generated ip_list.txt as demonstrated:

```sh
masscan -iL ip_list.txt -p 80
```

## edit

I found another command that can achieve the same parallel effect, but it's a bit more exciting as it's easier, which is `xarg`,an example syntax on how to use it is the following:

```sh
cat hosts.txt | xargs -n1 -P100 dig +short +retry=3 | grep -E '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' > ip_list.txt
```

- `-P100` specifies 100 parallel processes;
- `-n1` gets only the first argument of a line from hosts.txt (changing it to higher shouldn't have any effect, as long as the input file has only hostnames separated by newlines);
- The downside of this approach is that xargs doesn't retry if dig fails, but I used +retry for that;

Answer (score 2):

masscan does not provide any option to run scan on domain name you have to provide it list of ip address. So if you have a list of domain names in a file you can use following script to get ip address of all the domains.

```
$ cat hosts
github.com
google.com
pentestmonkey.com
```

script:

```
import sys
import socket
read_file = open('hosts','r')
for host in read_file:
    print socket.gethostbyname(host.rstrip("\n"))   #rstrip for removing new line characters
read_file.close()
```

Comment: gethostbyname is not defined

Comment: This will work but it isn't a good solution. Generally masscan is used to cover a lot of ground, extremely quickly. It is asynchronous, supports zero copy packet transmission, and is hands down the fastest software for doing large scans.

Doing DNS resolution with Python is not appropriate unless you're doing a test with a few dozen hosts (in which case you might as well just use nmap for everything and forget about masscan)

Comment: @adam Completely agree with you, A better choice will be massdns but that too has some draw backs like high rate of false positive if there are bad resolvers, which can be mitigated by using list of good resolver which also needs some more work and time if you never used it before. I recently build a script for personal use which can resolve 1000 domains in 3 sec I'll add it her once I open source it

Answer (score 0):

From the [**Comparison with Nmap** section of the masscan README.md](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan#comparison-with-nmap):

> You can think of masscan as having the following settings permanently
>   enabled:

...

> -n: no DNS resolution happens

So that tool will not facilitate conversion of the host names to IP addresses. You'll need to do that using a tool like `host` or `dig` and then feed the results into `masscan`.

`massscan` can [read scan ranges (i.e. IP addresses and CIDR blocks) from a file](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan/blob/f5926c97847b115c85d6e1672fcf53127552fc92/src/main-conf.c#L325), using the [`-iL <filename>` flag](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan/blob/f5926c97847b115c85d6e1672fcf53127552fc92/src/main-conf.c#L160).

---

Also worth mentioning, here's [another excerpt from README.md](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan#how-to-scan-the-entire-internet):

> Scanning the entire Internet is bad. For one thing, parts of the
>   Internet react badly to being scanned. For another thing, some sites
>   track scans and add you to a ban list, which will get you firewalled
>   from useful parts of the Internet.

If the "millions of domain names" aren't under your control, the warning above is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a high-speed (parallel or async) mass DNS resolver ([massdns](https://github.com/blechschmidt/massdns), [fernmelder](https://github.com/mzpqnxow/fernmelder), etc.) to get the IP addresses for each DNS name efficiently. Use the IP addresses as input for masscan. If you'd like, you can plug the DNS names back in to the masscan JSON output with a dozen lines of Python.

Unless you're working on a very small scale, do **NOT** use Python or nmap to do your DNS resolution. You need native code to do this well, hence the recommendation for [massdns](https://github.com/blechschmidt/massdns) or [fernmelder](https://github.com/mzpqnxow/fernmelder)

Comment: Hey adam, not sure if you'll see this but I'm trying to solve this exact problem right now. I resolved a list of hostnames to their IPs, ran them through masscan to find hosts listening on a specific port, and now I have a flat list of all those IPs. I want to match that list of IPs to the relevant hostnames in the original file but I can't think of an efficient way to accomplish this. Every solution I can come up with involves searching file 2 for every line in file 1 which seems like it will take a lot of time. Any advice?

Comment: You're going to have to write code to do this. You can do it relatively quickly using Python- load each dataset into a dict using IP address as the dict key and iterate through in a loop (kind of clunky and slow) or you can use something like Pandas to do this with a lot less code and a lot more efficiently, but it will require Pandas experience. Roughly, you'll need to load each dataset into a separate DataFrame, do a bit of processing on the massdns DataFrame, and ultimately use a merge operation and a melt operation to push the FQDN into the masscan data